# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Secure-NSUserDefaults library

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I am trying to use the Secure-NSUserDefaults library found here: https://github.com/matthiasplappert/Secure-NSUserDefaults

This function crashes when I try to hash an integer using the library:

```
- (NSString *)_hashObject:(id)object
{
    if (_secretData == nil) 
    {
        // Use if statement in case asserts are disabled
        NSAssert(NO, @"Provide a secret before using any secure writing or reading methods!");
        return nil;
    }

    // Copy object to make sure it is immutable (thanks Stephen)
    object = [object copy];

    // Archive & hash
    NSMutableData *archivedData = [[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object] mutableCopy];
    [archivedData appendData:_secretData];

    if (_deviceIdentifierData != nil)
        [archivedData appendData:_deviceIdentifierData];

    NSString *hash = [self _hashData:archivedData];

    return hash;
}
```

After stepping through the debugger it appears that this line in particular is the culprit:

```
NSMutableData *archivedData = [[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object] mutableCopy];
```

This method returns nil, and corrupts the address of object (which becomes 0xffffffcc). Note that I've never actually used NSKeyedArchiver before so I don't quite understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Integers aren't objects in Objective-C. You cannot pass them to a method that takes an object argument.

I'm not really clear on why you're using an `NSKeyedArchiver` for this. If you need an `NSMutableData` there, you probably want to create one directly using [`dataWithBytes:length:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-CIADICEA)

Comment: Actually, the integer is ultimately converted into an NSNumber before it gets passed into the hashObject() method. I tried [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:object length:malloc_size(object)] but still get a nil return value, and object becomes nil as well.

Comment: Nevermind, I decided it's simpler to just write the hash myself rather than use a broken library.